# Grover / Puppeteer: When generating a PDF from an HTML page, the PDF file has an unwanted white border

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, puppeteer, pdf-generation, grover

I am using [Grover](https://github.com/Studiosity/grover) / [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.pdfoptions.md) to convert an HTML page to a PDF.

The HTML page renders in the desired way.

But, when creating the PDF, there is a white border on the far right side of the page, which isn't there on the HTML page.

[Screenshot of the PDF with white space on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkAEm.png)

---

This is the portion of my page, which is positioned on the far right when rendered as a HTML page, but not when converted into a PDF:

```
<div class="inline-block overflow-hidden absolute top-0 right-0 w-[140px]">
 <div class="transform origin-top-left -rotate-45 bg-brand-primary h-[200px]">
 </div>
</div>
```

---

This is my `grover.rb` file:

```
# original resolution in HTML
width = 842
height = 595

Grover.configure do |config|
  config.options = {
    format: 'A4',
    landscape: true,
    print_background: true,
    wait_until: 'networkidle0',
    launch_args: \['--no-sandbox'\],
    viewport: {
     width:,
     height:
    },
    scale: 1 / 0.75
  }
end
```

I have tried adjusting the `width`, `height`, `format` and `scale` options in the `grover.rb` file and have also tried to modify the HTML (however, I suspect the issue lies in the options, as the HTML page renders as expected).

I expected the border to disappear... it didn't.
Would appreciate any hints! :)